# How to login in the database of entity framework context

Tags: linqpad, linqpad7

I'm trying to connect to my context in my VS solution with EF Core

[image: conexion]

But when I test the connection I get this error

[image: error]

Because it is trying to connect with my domain user instead the user in the connection string

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: If you add System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() to your DbContext's constructor, you'll be able to attach to Visual Studio and debug what's going on after clicking the Test button.

Comment: your user should have an account. the error is a login failed.

Comment: Sorry @PowerMouse but I don't understand you. What user?The user in the connection string or "Fulcrum\rquintela" and what account? Thanks

Comment: did you try to connect to sql with that user/pwd from sql management studio?

Comment: @PowerMouse in sql management studio I connect with the user and password of the connection string without any problem

Comment: use as multiprovider, and connect your dto classes an nuget?

Answer (score 0):

i cant post pictures in reply so i am using it as answer
i will doublecheck lower versions (i guess 5) - since i dont know which version are you using (but image of EF connection is different than mine (!))
[image]
in **linqpad 7** it works
[image]

[image]

in addition, if you need a context you can write using regular connection

```
using(TypedDataContext context = new TypedDataContext(Connection.ConnectionString)){
        
        context.TABLE.Where(w=>w.ID == 64463).Dump();
        
    }
```

[image]